# Database Mail - File Attachment Access Denied

Tags: sql, email-attachments, database-mail

We have a function that uses SP_Send_DBMail.  A user that has the DatabaseMailUserRole can send messages, but as soon as he attaches a file from a network share he receives the following error:

> MSG 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Failed to open Attachment file '\....'. Access Denied.

He has read / write permissions on the network share.
The SQLAgent account has read / write on the network share.

The application can send attachments fine, but he can't while walking the code or from the server.

If I grant him SysAdmin (only for testing) he can send the attachment.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is he running it from a remote computer? From Books Online: "Windows does not allow SQL Server to provide credentials from a remote computer to another remote computer. Therefore, Database Mail may not be able to attach files from a network share in cases where the command is run from a computer other than the computer that SQL Server runs on."

Comment: He is remotely connected via SSMS yes, but I am as well, and I can do it as a SysAdmin.  He can as well when granted SysAdmin role.

Comment: Try to map shared resource as local drive to server where SQL Server installed.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem and found a solution.

I gave delegation to sql server service account which is active directory account, then the problem disappeared. 
The application must be restarted after delegation permission configuration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJXPO.png)